# Python Linked List Merge Sort not working

Tags: python, linked-list, mergesort

I have this assignment for uni that I have been working on for some time now, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. The goal is to merge two already-sorted linked lists into one sorted linked list.

The only function that I am allowed to change is the merge(a,b) function. I triple-checked, but I keep getting the following error:

```
 in __repr__
    out += str(node.weight)
AttributeError: 'ItemList' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

Is there anyone that can figure out what I should change? I'm very lost.

My code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Node:
    weight: float
    link: Optional[Node] = None


def merge(a: ItemList, b: ItemList) -> c:
    """
    This function takes two linked lists, assumed sorted, and merges them
    in-place, without creating new Nodes, just by changing the links.
    """

    # create a new ItemList and dummynode as head:
    c = ItemList()
    c.head = Node(0)

    # List1 is empty then return b
    if a.head is None:
        c._length += len(b)
        b._length -= len(b)
        return b

    # if List2 is empty then return a
    if b.head is None:
        c._length += len(a)
        a._length -= len(a)
        return a

    # If the weight of the element of a is smaller or equal to b's weight
    if a.head.weight <= b.head.weight:

        # We assign the weight of a's head to the head of c
        c.head.weight = a.head.weight

        #Give list a a new head (depletion) and subtract one from the length of a
        a.head = a.head.link
        a._length -= 1

        # We will go through the algorithm again (recursively) to check for the element next-in-line.
        c.head.link = merge(a, b)

    # If the weight of the element of a is smaller or equal to b's weight
    else:
        # We assign the weight of a's head to the head of c
        c.head.weight = b.head.weight

        #Give list b a new head (depletion) and subtract one from the length of b
        b.head = b.head.link
        b._length -= 1

        # We will go through the algorithm again (recursively) to check for the element next-in-line.
        c.head.link = merge(a, b)

    # return the merged list
    return c

class ItemList:
    head: Optional[Node]

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize an empty linked list for warehouse items."""

        self.head = None
        self._length = 0

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._length

    def insert(self, val: int) -> ItemList:
        """Insert a new item with given weight, at the beginning of the list"""

        new_node = Node(weight=val, link=self.head)
        self.head = new_node
        self._length += 1
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        """This function prints the list in a nice way."""

        node = self.head
        out = "["
        while node is not None:
            out += str(node.weight)
            if node.link is not None:
                out += ", "
            node = node.link
        out += "]"
        return out

warehouse = (
    ItemList()
    .insert(8)
    .insert(6)
    .insert(4)
    .insert(2)
    .insert(0)
)
warehouse2 = (
    ItemList()
    .insert(9)
    .insert(7)
    .insert(5)
    .insert(3)
    .insert(1)
)
print(merge(warehouse,warehouse2))
```

Comment: your warehouses are reverse sorted, while your merge seems to assume to create an ascending array? This is not how 'merge sorted array' should work

Comment: True, I fixed it right after I saw it. Still doesn't work...

Comment: This line is wrong: c.head.link = merge(a, b) which assigns a LinkedList to a Node item. You need to rethink how this data strcture works

Comment: Thanks. My teacher demands the input of the function ```merge``` to be of two LinkedLists. Working on it to make it work. I'll let you know if I found the way forward.

Comment: I found it! It should be ```c.head.link = merge(a,b).head```. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive `mergeNodes` function:

```
def mergeNodes(a: Node, b: Node):
    """
    This function takes two linked lists of Nodes, assumed sorted, and
    merges them into a single linked list of Nodes, in-place, without
    creating new Nodes, just by changing the links.
    """
    if a is None:
        return b
    if b is None:
        return a
    if a.head.weight <= b.head.weight:
        a.link = mergeNodes(a.link, b)
        return a
    else
        b.link = mergeNodes(a, b.link)
        return b
```

Merging the lists becomes very simple:

```
def merge(a: ItemList, b: ItemList) -> ItemList:
    """
    This function takes two ItemList objects, assumed sorted, and merges them
    into a new ItemList, without creating new Nodes, just by changing the links.
    the original objects are destroyed
    """

    # create a new ItemList:
    c = ItemList()
    c._length = a._length + b._length;
    c.head = mergeNodes(a.head, b.head)
    # clear the original lists because the links are no longer consistent
    a._length = 0
    a.head = None
    b._length = 0
    b.head = None
    return c
```

Note that `merge` should be a method of class `ItemList` and merge a list passed as an argument into `self`.